# How to skip if any exception come while storing data to the database using java?

Tags: java, exception

I have a Entity named `MyData`. And I am trying to add `MyData` entity's values to database. Like below:

```
for (MyDataParent myDataParent : myDataParentList) {
    MyData myData = new Mydata();
    myData.setName("Hello");
    myData.setNumber("1234567890");
    myData.setGender("Male");

    this.storeAndflush(myData);
}
```

And I want to skip inserting this `myData` entity if any exception occurred while storing data and continue to the loop. What is the way to do?

Comment: Enclose the the code from the loop body in `try {...} catch (Exception ex) {...}` and handle the `Exception`, maybe log it along with the dataset to be aware of what was written or not.

Comment: Solution aside, continuing on an exception in this scenario is usually a bad idea, as it means you're either not doing proper integrity checks before storage, or your connection has broken, which will trigger the same error on the next try

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I can not add Exception class in catch block because if any exception occurs then it will be catched by catch block and then it terminates the loop.

Comment: Just wrap this line `this.storeAndflush(myData);` inside try catch block, this way the loop will not be interrupted. So the try catch should be inside the loop not the other way around (the loop inside try catch block)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `try-catch` block and log the relevant exception. If you are using SQL database it most likely will be [`SQLException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/SQLException.html).

```
for (MyDataParent myDataParent : myDataParentList) {
  MyData myData = new Mydata();
  myData.setName("Hello");
  myData.setNumber("1234567890");
  myData.setGender("Male");

  try {
    this.storeAndflush(myData);
  } catch (SQLException ex) {
    logger.log(ex);
  }
}
```

Try not to catch all possible exceptions e.g. don't catch `Exception` or `Throwable`. Handle only these which are related to persistence to ensure that you are not hiding implementation errors.